# Realm crashes in react-native for android 10?

Tags: react-native, realm

We have recently updated our react-native project to 0.62.2. To perform the linking we need to update the realm version to 6.0.0. It is working fine on ios but it is crashing on android 10 only. Below android 10 it is also working fine. We have realm version 0f 0.29.2 initially. After that we again degraded the version of realm to 0.29.2 then it is working fine. We have also updated the version above 6 also but the same problem occurs.

How can we update our realm to 6.0.0 or any version above it for android 10?